# Web Scraping with auto login JAVA

Tags: java, web-scraping

I want to extract a line of text from the website : "http://dunkmantips.com/vip-tips/vip-live-530/" but i cant because I need to login in first. Firefox has already saved my credentials and autologins, if I open the website manually.

How can I extract text from an authorized page?

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println(getURLSource("http://dunkmantips.com/vip-tips/vip-live-530/"));
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



private static String toString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
{
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")))
    {
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int line=0;
        while (((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null))
        {
            if (inputLine.contains("<!-- Share buttons by mashshare.net - Version: 3.5.3--><span class=\"cb-itemprop\" itemprop=\"reviewBody\"><p>")) {
                System.out.println("FOUND IT!!");
            }

            //stringBuilder.append(inputLine+"\r\n");
            line++;
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

public static String getURLSource(String url) throws IOException
{
    URL urlObject = new URL(url);
    URLConnection urlConnection = urlObject.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");

    return toString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
}
```

Comment: The easy solution is to just perform the authentication through your automated web browsing. I'm not sure of the library your using, but you could just first navigate to the login screen and enter your credentials before trying to access the page yo want

Comment: there isnt a logging screen just a popup window,and i dont know how to find it.I use java.net.URL. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That popup window is indicative of so called "plain authentication".
You may want to use a client library to retrieve the URL, for example Apache HttpClient.

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/project-reports.html

Depending on the version, you may want to use class DefaultHttpClient or HttpClientBuilder and set a CredentialProvider on it. If so, the library will take care of presenting your credential to the server.